# Why is returning null values by using bind_param in Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to get the first record in a database table, and i need the function bind_param of Mysqli.

```
$query = "SELECT `username`,`password` FROM `user` WHERE `id` = ?";
$result = $mysqli->prepare($query) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$query]");
$id = 1;
$result->bind_param("i",$id);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: Should the `I` in bind_param be lowercase? and you should set the value of `$id` before passing it to bind_param

Comment: I think this line should be: $result->bind_param("1",$id); as it seems to me that id field is integer & you are putting string

Comment: Your code is fine, but I must be lowercase i.e (i).

Comment: @Dale is correct. it should be `i`, not `I`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
Adding `$result->bind_result($username,$password)` after `$result->execute()`